# parsing html using awk to get content between two div tags

Tags: shell, awk

```
<div class="command">ans1</div>
    <div class="num-votes" id="num-votes-9598">0</div>
    
    <div class="command">ans2</div>
    <div class="num-votes" id="num-votes-9590">7</div>
```

I would like to extract the value in class='command' like ans1 or ans2 depending on the value in class='num-votes' which should be greater than or equal to 5.

for example, in the above example we get ans2, instead ans1, as num-votes value is 7 which is greater than 5.

How can i do this using awk?? totally new to shell scripting so i am struggling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are new to shell scripting, but then who or what gave you the impression `awk` is the proper tool for this? It may be a pragmatic approach, but in general, I would not recommend using `awk` for HTML scraping. In your HTML input, are the opening and closing tag guaranteed to be on the same line? Is it possible for the content to contain (nested) HTML tags? Could the content contain characters that need to be HTML-decoded?

Comment: I do know that task like this can be performed easily using python, i was just going through a book and had to solve the above question using any command line tool, so i thought awk might be a good tool, but i could never figure the solution out. can you suggest any command line tool to solve this.

Comment: Since html is free-format, you should use a proper [html parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+parser) to get the file into some reasonable format, then use awk to extract what you need.

Comment: If you make some assumptions (for starters, that the HTML is "sane"), you can use an awk, or even a sed/grep pipeline. But you might be better off with a programming language library, such as in perl, or python, or .. Is it your true desire to use purely awk for this?

Comment: can i know how i can solve this using sed/grep.

Comment: It is impossible to come up with a solution from 2 lines of html from a file that no doubt has numerous lines.